# Enabling SQL Server TCP/IP protocol with Tomcat v7

Tags: sql-server, eclipse, tomcat

I'm working on Spring project using Tomcat as server, My database in SQL Server 2008 r2. whenever I enable the TCP/IP protocol of SQL Server, if I restert the Tomcat Server it gives me this error:

> Starting Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem
>
> Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45
>   seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout
>   in the server editor.

I tried to inrease in start time but I encountred the same problem. If disable the TCP/IP protocol of SQL Server and I restert the Tomcat Server it works.

Best regards.

Comment: How is your SQLServer connection configured? Do any errors or messages related to the database appear in your Tomcat logs?

Comment: only the errors i received are concerned my DAO